# Process of packages loading

Tags: use-package, list, quote

It seems I totally do not understand the mechanism of package loading in Emacs.

I have in my init.el something like this:

```
(use-package elpy
  :ensure t
  :init
  (elpy-enable)
  :config
  (defalias 'workon 'pyvenv-workon)
  (setenv "WORKON_HOME" "/home/algor/miniconda3/envs")
  :custom
  (elpy-modules (elpy-module-sane-defaults
                 elpy-module-company
                 elpy-module-eldoc
                 elpy-module-pyvenv))
  (eldoc-idle-delay 5))
```

As I understand, first of all it loads a file containing `(provide 'elpy)`, in my case it is `.emacs.d/elpa/elpy-20220203.108/elpy.el`.

But after starting Emacs I get the following errors:

```
Error (use-package): elpy/:init: Symbol’s function definition is void: elpy-module-sane-defaults
Error (use-package): elpy/:catch: Symbol’s function definition is void: elpy-module-sane-defaults
```

Also, I check that this function doesn't exist by hand.

It looks quite strange to me since I can find the definition of this function in elpy.el. I also can execute the definition by C-x C-e, and after that I can check that the function exists.

Am I wrong that the file elpy.el is executed while emacs is starting?

Comment: Stab in the dark: do you need to quote the list?

Comment: you could try adding `:demand t` to your configuration to make sure `use-package` isn't deferring loading of your config. you could also try your customization out in non-`use-package` form to make sure it is formatted right.

Comment: This may be a duplicate question. I searched for that (tag `quote` etc.), but didn't find a dup. If someone finds one then this question should probably by closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nickd suggested in a comment, try quoting the list.

```lisp
  (elpy-modules '(elpy-module-sane-defaults
                  elpy-module-company
                  elpy-module-eldoc
                  elpy-module-pyvenv))
```

It looks like the code produced by `use-package` is *evaluating* what you provide for the list of modules. Instead of providing something that evaluates to a list of modules, you provided a sexp that's a list with car `elpy-module-sane-defaults`. That sexp gets *evaluated*, as an application of the (supposed) function `elpy-module-sane-defaults` to the other list elements.

Comment: Thank you, it helps!

But I don't understand why the error was "Symbol’s function definition is void". If the sexp tried to be evalueted then the error should be "wrong arguments" or something like that, should't it?

Comment: It was trying to call `elpy-module-sane-defaults` as a function: I don't know if it is a function or not (haven't checked), but even if it is, it is not defined yet at that point. But you'd have to dig into `use-package` to see what it is actually doing.

Comment: The sexp is a (nonempty) list. Such a sexp is evaluated as a function application. Its first element is regarded as a function, and that is applied to the evaluations of the other elements (the arguments to the function). The argument elements are evaluated in order. When the car (first element) of the list is a symbol, its function value (what is returned by passing that symbol to function `symbol-function`) is used as the function to be applied to the arguments (evaluations of the other list elements).

Comment: See the Elisp manual, node [Function Forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Forms.html).

Comment: @NickD's comment here is a valid point. I just took a guess that this should be a quoted list.

Comment: I guess that `:custom` part of use-package sexp is executed before the package is loaded. That makes sense, thank you!